# Infinite scroll on a Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need a Wordpress plugin that will allow me to add photos, small message boxes etc. and show them into a specific page (where I want to display it), but with an infinite scroll feature (show/load them while scrolling the page).

Is there such a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [AJAX Load More](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/) as you can create a custom loop template fairly easily to achieve the result you a are looking for. (Similar can be done with Jetpack, but this one has more flexibility.)